# Cannot `create function` in plpython3u, permission denied

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, postgresql-9.1, plpython

As postgres user, I have `create extension plpython3u;` in my database

then I have set the `plpython3u` to trusted: `select lanpltrusted from pg_language where lanname like 'plpython3u';` returns true

but when my db_user tries

```
  create function check_data_valid(id bigint)
    returns boolean
    as $$
    -- ...
    return true
    $$ language plpython3u;
```

I got the error: `permission denied for the language plpython3u`

So, with my postgres user then I have tried: `grant usage on plpython3u to db_user` and `grant execute on plpython3u to db_user` but both returns the error:

`relation python doesn't exist`

maybe it's because it's an extension... however, I don't what to do so as to create my stored procedure.

Comment: If you're letting them use `plpython3u` you might as well just make them a superuser anyway; they can fairly easily make themselves a superuser from within a Python script. (This isn't a good reason to make them a superuser, it's a good reason not to use `plpython3u` for user-written procedures).

Comment: @CraigRinger you do think it's the solution ?

Comment: @CraigRinger i am the user and the admin... but I want to keep both role seperated.

Comment: BTW the [`GRANT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-grant.html) you're looking for is `GRANT USAGE ON LANGUAGE plpython3u TO db_user`.

Comment: that's right... it works better !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First *don't* make plpython3u into a trusted language.  This is *bad.*  You are giving access to all kinds of things on the database, the filesystem, and the like in ways that could be horribly abused.  **Please reconsider.**

Now from your comments you want to keep the admin permission separate from the normal user permission.  The way to do this is to make sure the superuser is NOINHERIT and the user is granted the role.  You can:

```
 CREATE ROLE mydba WITH SUPERUSER NOINHERIT;

 GRANT mydba TO myuser;
```

Then logged in as `myuser` then you can:

```
 SET ROLE mydba;
```

And you get superuser privileges.  You can use this to then to temporarily escalate your permissions in a way similar to sudo on *nix systems.

Comment: do you mean: in real life, the use of PL/Python and PL/C is discouraged ? There are no other trusted languages than PL/pgSQL ?

Comment: I don't mean that at all.  It does mean that you need to very carefully control *who* can create these procedures and what they do.  Also there is a trusted version of pl/perl.  You may find this interesting: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PL_Matrix

Comment: okay, myuser has to use carefully the `set role mydba`. Does it goes off after psql connection ? or should I manually `set role none` when done with programming the stored procedure in untrusted language ?

Comment: `RESET ROLE;` resets it

Comment: @ChrisTravers Or in this case even better, `myplpythonuser` that you `GRANT USAGE` to without having to make them otherwise a superuser.

Comment: I'm gonna create both roles.

Comment: @CraigRinger however if the language is not trusted, even with grant usage, myplpythonuser still cannot create functions. this is reserved to superuser.

Comment: Objects created after running `SET ROLE mydba` will be owned by that role. If you decide one day to "revoke sudo" from myuser, they will lose access to those objects. I think you need to `ALTER ROLE mydba NOSUPERUSER` to effectively "disable sudo access".

Comment: I don't think that's true.  I think you can reassign untrusted language functions to another user.  But only superuser can create such functions.